# Tag proposal: squeeze-theorem

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

There are many questions about the squeeze theorem on this site, and seeing that some other theorems such as the Chinese Remainder Theorem, Stokes theorem, Bayes theorem, etc. have their own tags, why not this one?

> Note: A [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=squeeze+theorem++is%3Aq) yielded $668$ results, compared to searches for [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=chinese+remainder+theorem+is%3Aq) with $745$ results, [Stokes Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stokes+theorem+is%3Aq) with $700$ results, [Bayes Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=bayes+theorem+is%3Aq) with $438$ results.
>   I know the searches aren't too accurate, but they give a general representation of how often a theorem is asked about.

Comment: You should at least restrict the searches to questions, adding "is:q" It does not change your point much (thou a bit) but still. Tangentially, why didn't you post in the tag-management thread?

Comment: @quid edited the post

Comment: This tag seems like it wouldn't benefit the question askers. Would the type of askers who would use this tag go to the trouble of checking previously asked questions in the tag to see if they could solve their problems using answers already given? I doubt it. So then are there enough interested squeeze-theorem question answerers who would follow this tag? I think that's the main point in whether it should be created.

Comment: @AntonioVargas How about for people looking for different applications of the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @suomynonA, Isn't that more efficiently done by just searching for "squeeze theorem"? That would find all tagged questions plus many questions not in the tag. So no, I don't see creating the tag as helping in that direction.

Comment: @AntonioVargas If you want to put it like that, why have any tags at all? Why not just let users search?

Comment: Of course they're useful in other cases, and I'm not saying this tag wouldn't be useful. I just don't think its usefulness would be as a search aid in this particular case. Like I said, I think it could be useful to motivated answerers who want to follow the tag, given enough of them exist. That's what's not clear to me.

Comment: @AntonioVargas That's what I mean; some people may find it useful, but it can also be used as an easy search (simply clicking on the tag in a tagged question)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it is usual for question to be *about* a squeeze theorem.

There are common beginning problems in analysis whose *solution* involves squeezing, but the question *itself* will rarely be about squeezing.

In particular, I have trouble imagining anyone would like to filter or search questions based on whether the answers employ a squeeze theorem, so the practical utility of having a tag seems to be small.

Comment: It would be useful tag for a teacher who search for exercises on squeeze theorem for his students

Comment: What about questions specifically regarding how to use the squeeze theorem as a solution method?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Such questions are rare, in my experience.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the search statistics say otherwise.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Also writing "squeeze theorem" in the search field can do that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what does that have to do with me saying that questions involving the squeeze theorem aren't as rare as Makholm thinks?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: It's a reply to your first comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, and that comment was a reply to this "There are common beginning problems in analysis whose solution involves squeezing, but the question itself will **rarely be about squeezing**.". Then I said, well what if the question specifically wanted the squeezing method or wanted to discuss proofs of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Your first comment is the first comment. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I quoted the post I was responding to. There is a post before my first comment here and I was responding to this post we are all commenting on. Surely you know there is a post at the head of this thread right? Or did MSE decide to throw a comment to the wrong thread *again*. I noticed that it's been doing that every once in a while.

Answer (score 6):

The squeeze-theorem is a useful device (with a nice name) for students just beginning to understand limits. I doubt that it occurs by name often (ever) in more advanced mathematics. Your other examples are well known named tools in a mathematicians toolkit.

That's a reason not to  have a tag for squeeze-theorem. On the other hand, many questioners here are just learning to reason about limits, so perhaps the new tag is warranted.

Let's see what others say.

Comment: Good point, +1. How about the other theorems that have tags? Sorry, I don't know all of them so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Well, not everyone goes past elementary calculus so perhaps the tag is useful for the broader audience?

Comment: Counterexample to it never appearing by name: it's used to prove the mean first recurrence theorem of Markov chains (i.e., mean time to reach state $j$ from state $j$ is $1 / \pi_j$, where $\pi_j$ is the limiting/stationary/long-run-time-average probability of being in state $j$), and is cited by name on page 168 of [_Performance Modeling and Design of Computer Systems_](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~harchol/PerformanceModeling/book.html). :-)

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe the tag is useful and should be warranted. For instance, there are many reasons I can see it being used for all listed below:

1. Asking how to solve a problem via squeeze theorem.
2. Questions regarding the squeeze theorem itself (such as proof of the theorem itself).
3. A way for people to find squeeze theorem questions if they need some for examples in exercises, self-study, etc.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the points mentioned in this post...

Comment: @suomynonA people disagreed with me therefore they downvoted.

Comment: Looks pretty controversial, +7/-7 on this answer and lots of upvotes and downvotes on the rest...

Comment: @suomynonA well, people aren't voting based on what they think is logical. They are voting on what they agree with.